# How does c++ handle an unknown size array allocation during compilation stage

Tags: c++, arrays

I have learned that c++ use relative distances during compilation stage in order to increase the performance of the code. For instance, it knows that the distance of two local integers is 4.
My question is about arrays with unknown size during compilation

For example , the compiler does not have information the amount of memory it should allocate for the local array in the following code:
How does it know the relative distance between the local variables local2 and size

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int size = std::getchar();
    int arr[size];
    int local2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is _not_ valid C++.

Comment: was compiled successfully https://ideone.com/SsvycN

Comment: @ldan I didn't say it wouldn't compile. I just said it wasn't valid C++.

Comment: If a code was compiled and was run successfully, it is a valid code . It might not be a good code , but it is valid

Comment: @ldan Some compilers implement non-standard features and you seem to have come across one or several of those. That doesn't make it valid code, however. Have you read the question and answers linked to by Crazy Eddie?

Comment: @Idan - A great many C++ compilers double as C compilers.  So they happen to support features that exist in C.  They *should* differentiate so that you can't attempt this, but most don't.  Most in fact compile code with their own extensions turned on without warnings.  In g++ for example you have to set the std flag, like -std=c++11.  Still then you have to turn on -pedantic.  Only then will g++ tell you that you're using non-standard constructs and I don't know that it will catch this particular one.  You can't use successful compilation as proof your code is valid.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN , I already said this is a bad code, so your question is irrelevant. Thanks for your help, I will enable more warning next time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Variable length arrays don't exist in C++: [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c)

So the answer to your question is: the compiler has no way of knowing and shouldn't try.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't. and it's a compile time error. You'd want to look into pointers and dymanic memory allocations/deallocations. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new

basically, for single instances you'd use new/delete. and for arrays you'd use new[]/delete[]. Don't combine new with delete[] and new[] with delete. Bad things will happen.